# How to create StackedColumn chart in ASP.NET?

Tags: c#, asp.net, charts, stacked

I have a dataset that I want rendered as a stacked column chart using the built-in charting in VS 2010. The data looks like this and is returned from SQL Server from a stored procedure:

```
numTrades   Type    symbol
3   BreakEven   GBPCHF
7   Loss    GBPCHF
11  Win GBPCHF
1   BreakEven   GBPJPY
3   Loss    GBPJPY
7   Win GBPJPY
7   Loss    GBPUSD
13  Win GBPUSD
```

My ASP.Net code for rendering the chart looks like this:

```
<asp:Chart 
    ID="chtWinnerPercentagePie" 
    runat="server" 
    DataMember="DefaultView" 
    Height="600px" 
    Palette="Pastel" 
    Width="900px"  
    AlternateText="WinLoss Pie" 
    SkinID="chartSkin"
    ImageType="Png" >
   <Series >
      <asp:Series 
        Name="WinnersLosers" 
        ChartType="StackedColumn"
        ChartArea="MainChartArea" 
        XValueMember="symbol" 
        YValueMembers="numTrades">             
      </asp:Series>          
   </Series>       
   <Legends>
    <asp:Legend Name="Legend" ForeColor="#A1A5A9" BackColor="#161616" />
   </Legends>
   <ChartAreas>       
      <asp:ChartArea 
        Name="MainChartArea" 
        BackColor="#2C2C2C">
        <AxisY Title="Num Trades" TitleForeColor="White"> 
            <LabelStyle ForeColor="White" />                   
            <MajorGrid LineColor="#000000" />
        </AxisY>
        <AxisX Enabled="True">
            <LabelStyle ForeColor="White" />
        </AxisX>
      </asp:ChartArea>
   </ChartAreas>
    <Titles>
        <asp:Title 
            Name="ChartTitle" 
            Text="Win/Loss Ratio" 
            Font="Microsoft Sans Serif, 10pt" 
            ForeColor="#A1A5A9" 
            BackColor="#161616">
        </asp:Title>
    </Titles>
</asp:Chart>
```

I am not getting a stacked chart, I get this instead when I load the page:
http://tinypic.com/r/66kljl/7

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't you need more than one Series for a stacked chart?  I believe you need to create three for what you want.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at:

http://liberofusioncharts.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Single%20Series%20Chart,%20adding%20data%20manually&referringTitle=Home

Just need to change the line 1st line in the c# code:

from: Column3DChart oChart = new Column3DChart();

to  : StackedBar2DChart oChart = new StackedBar2DChart();

[image]